# Using Eloquent Laravel to show country's levels with big data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatables

I have a table `locations` (about 35000 rows and more than in the future).

[image]
[image]

I search on the internet and try it: [Eloquent: Recursive hasMany Relationship with Unlimited Subcategories](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-recursive-hasmany-relationship-with-unlimited-subcategories/)

I try to run it, it kept loading and did not stop. I think so data is big.

In addition, the above solution shows the **tree**. I want to show the **table**
[image]

I want to set up a query using eloquent model or anything to pass to the view (can use DataTables package)

Thanks so much!

Comment: `browser is unable to load` - what does that mean, exactly? Be specific.  What do your Laravel, PHP, and web server logs show?

Comment: @Don'tPanic oh, I'm sorry. The server did not respond to anything, it kept loading and did not stop. I think so data is big

Comment: If it is a timeout or out of memory error that will show up in your logs.  What do your Laravel, PHP, and web server logs show?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, The server is still not responding, I'm still waiting...

Comment: @Don'tPanic, it worked. but It is the tree format, I want to the table format. But the loading time is too long